# Check for full trust

Tags: .net, code-access-security, full-trust, partial-trust

How do I check if my code is running in full trust mode? I have seen several suggestions to check for specific permissions using `SecurityManager.IsGranted()` method, but I specifically want to check for full trust because no specific permission in partial trust mode is enough to use FileSystemWatcher class.

Comment: Which version of .NET?  Also, where/when do you want to make the check and what do you want to do with the result?

Comment: .NET 3.5 and 4.0. I have some code fragment that is handy but not crucial for the operation of my app so in case I do not have full trust it will simply be skipped. Right now the best I can think of is to try to run the code and catch SecurityException and ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there's only one approach that will work for transparent code (which yours will presumably be under at least 4.0 if it's not fully trusted) in both 3.5 and 4.0: demanding an unrestricted permission set and catching the SecurityException if the demand fails. e.g.:

```
public static bool RunningWithFullTrust()
{
    bool result;
    try
    {
        (new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted)).Demand();
        result = true;
    }
    catch (SecurityException)
    {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

This probably offers no advantage whatsoever over your current approach of catching and ignoring the exception.

For 4.0, there is a new [AppDomain.IsFullyTrusted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.isfullytrusted.aspx) method that would potentially be of use.